# "Reviewer" badge cannot be selected as the "Next Badge"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Why aren't the reviewer or steward badges shown or selectable as "next badge" on the user activity page? They are shown among the help-center badges.

Comment: (i) When I read the title I thought "I haven't heard of the 'Bug Reviewer'  badge -- what's that one for?". (ii) This might get more traction on meta.SE

Comment: @Glen_b Bug; Reviewer...

Comment: I'd likely have said "Bug$:$ *Reviewer* badge ..."

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it doesn't work in titles. But you can always do $\textit{Reviewer}$ or `Reviewer`. The point was really about the colon rather than the semi-colon

Comment: @Glen_b Gee, you are fast.

Comment: Too much to do to be slow

Comment: @Glen_b BTW, I used a semicolon because it means "that is" as opposed to a colon that means "list" although you are correct in the sense that a colon looks better.

Comment: Instead of an update, consider posting an answer quoting the reply you got on meta.SE and then accepting this answer.

Comment: @amoeba OK, done. Now, why did I do that? What difference does that make?

Comment: Not much :-) but now the thread is marked green as containing an accepted answer. This is pleasing to the eye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note also, as suggested, I asked this question on SE meta, and the answer [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286269/reviewer-steward-and-other-badges-not-selectable) was

> These badges are intentionally not available in the badge progress selector because they would require additional UI to select which queue you wanted to track which is simply not worth implementing at this time given that you can easily track these in each queue respectively.

Answer (score 8):

Quite a few badges aren't in the tracking list. (There are about 15 badges I don't have but only 4 show up that I can choose between for tracking)

Some of those at least will probably be for reasons of overhead (it would be too hard to keep doing the calculation every time you load your profile).

Some will be absent because you don't really "progress" toward them.

Some will be absent because they're already shown elsewhere. The reviewer progress is shown in information under the "review" menu item / review queues (e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats shows close-reviewer badge progress, https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats shows suggested-edit reviewer badge progress and so on)

So I expect that they don't show up because you're already getting a display that's "tracking" them elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I know. But, it annoyed me that it is not consistent. (+1)

Comment: I'm curious to know what happens after I get those last 4 badges I can track. Soon it will be down to three.

Comment: Interesting question. I hope it doesn't cause an error. Let me know if you can remember when you get them all.

Comment: Are you going for `peer pressure`? That's the one I'm tracking. (It's not clear I'll ever get legendary...)

Comment: @gung So you are. If that question was to me, I had no trouble getting `peer pressure`, all I had to do was try to clarify AIC. Since it is clear as mud to begin with, and there are armed camps within the AIC community, and an anti-BIC sub group, the mud slinging was immediate. Glen_b doesn't seem to have `peer pressure` either. Ah, you haven't lived until your colleagues throw mud at you. Wait one, *colleagues* can I even use that word? I am not a statistician by formal training. Maybe *kindred spirits.*

Comment: @gung Peer pressure is one of the four I can track (I am a single downvote off being able to delete the post in question and get it -- but nobody has given the third downvote on the post in several years. It didn't occur to me that tracking it might act as a signal. I should do that).  I'm just a few edits shy of Illuminator so I have been tracking that. I'll change that shortly. However, you appear to have deleted your few answers with fewer than 0 points so there wouldn't be much point in tracking that one for you.

Comment: Carl a lot of people here are from some other area "by formal training" -- including several of our top users (who goes to university to try to be a statistician? Most of us end up there almost by accident). I think there's no issue saying "colleague".

Comment: @Glen_b, itching for a downvote? What post ;-)?

Comment: @gung If you're inclined, you can find it by sorting my answers by votes and going to the last page. It deserves deletion; I only kept it around so that it might get the third downvote first. If you want to get it you have to leave a post with a downvote or two on it undeleted. And then wait. If you delete *all* the posts that garner downvotes there's no way to get -3. Well, outside posting something terrible deliberately I guess, but I can't bring myself to that.

Comment: @Carl if there was ever a bug with getting all trackable badges it would have been hit on StackOverflow dozens of times.  My guess is they considered what to do with any empty list when they first wrote it.

Comment: @Glen_b, I'm [on record](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189444/187282) stating that `Peer Pressure` is a badge people shouldn't want to get. But I'm willing to downvote you, if it will make you happy.

Comment: @gung Hey, if you deleted that one you could get peer pressure you know... :P .... I wouldn't have thought about it but I had a post on -2 anyway, so I figured there was little harm in waiting to see if someone would delete it. If you find the post worth a downvote, by all means do so, but I'm not going to ask you to (nor even directly link it, though it's easily found); asking for votes - even a single downvote - would be abusive I think.

Comment: I have no interest in deleting that (I'm not sure if it works for questions anyway); I put a lot of effort into raising the issue, researching it, laying out my arguments cogently, etc. That clearly isn't valued on MSE. The comments are mostly obnoxious, & the primary answer is a complete non-sequitur. Perhaps someday someone will bother to actually think about what I said, but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: It was meant as a joke (poking fun at myself, in fact); I can see the care that went in.